# Creating Random Div with Plain JavaScript /no jQuery/

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a random div between 100px and 400px with plain javascript. Random position may help as well :) Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How to create and style an element is a pretty basic question. Have you searched for an answer? It's really easy. And what do you mean by a "random div"? And what is 100px and 400px? The dimensions?

Comment: Yes, I did search for this, and yes, the dimensions are 100/100 to 400/400. If you can point me to the question where it is explained with plain javascript?

And being basic doesn't help. I know how basic it is.

Comment: You searched for how to create a `div`, and couldn't find it?

Comment: Seems like a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go,

```
window.onload = function(){
  randomDiv();
}

function randomDiv(){
  var w = Math.random() * 300 + 100;
  var h = Math.random() * 300 + 100;

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.cssText = "position: absolute; background-color: red;";

        div.style.width = w + "px";
        div.style.height = h + "px";
  div.style.top  = (Math.random() * window.innerHeight - h) + "px";
  div.style.left = (Math.random() * window.innerWidth - w) + "px";

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at:

- element.style.width
- element.style.height
- Math.random

To generate a random integer between 100 and 400 you can do this:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*300)+100;
```

If you want to place the div randomly you will want to look at these CSS properties:

- position
- top
- left